# Incorrect direction of element using anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I am currently working in a blog website, it is made using HTML and CSS.
In this, on the top navigation bar, when I click on the Contact button, I get redirected to the environment section, instead I should be redirected to the contacts section which is at the bottom of the website. 
Link for the blog website: https://riyad-dev.github.io/Personal-Blog/

HTML code:

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://seeklogo.com/images/B/blogger_B-logo-47610B2F87-seeklogo.com.png">
        <title>Blog</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar-inverse" style="position:sticky;top:0;z-index:99999">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Rishabh Yadav</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#travel">TRAVEL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#movies">MOVIES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#environment">ENVIRONMENT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#books">BOOKS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header" id="travel">
                <h2 class="text-capitalize">Places Must Visit</h2>
            </div>
            <center>
                <div class="travel_mainDiv">
                    <img class="img_responsive" src="Images/trave1.jpeg">
                    <h4 class="text-capitalize">
                        <kbd>
                            Prithvi Cafe
                        </kbd>
                    </h4>
                    <hr>
                    <h5 class="text-success text-capitalize text-left">
                        I have visited this place in December 2019.
                    </h5>
                    <p class="text-muted text-left">
                        Quaint little restaurant tucked inside a by-lane of Juhu. Blink and you will miss the entrance to the cafe. So be alert enough to spot the black signboard that says "Prithvi cafe" while you are on the main road. The restaurant has a reasonably good menu at reasonable prices. The food is delicious, the servings are quite large and some dishes can be shared by 2 people. Attracts quite a trendy crowd of aspiring celebrities on show days. Be sure to book in advance to avoid disappointments. On other days, the crowd there is pretty hep and happening. Hosts the famous "Prithvi theater fest", which you must attend if possible.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </center>

            <br><br>

            <center>
                <div class="travel_mainDiv">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="Images/travel2.jpeg">

                    <h4 class="text-capitalize"><kbd>Jantar Mantar - Jaipur</kbd></h4>

                    <hr>

                    <h5 class="text-success text-left text-capitalize">I had visited in Feb 2019</h5>

                    <p class="text-muted text-left">It's a wonderful place. Must visit this place. Must haired tour guide so it will be batter to under stand all the things. It is a beautifully maintained small complex with yellow painted walls. It's a historical site famous among tourists. It contains a number of different devices that were used to measure time in different eras in the Indian history. It has a nominal ticket price of ₹15 for Indians but about ₹225-250 for foreigners. Nice place to visit. We had an incredible experience visiting this observatory and seeing the accuracy of the astronomical instruments built around 300 years ago.</p>
                </div>
            </center>

            <br><br>

            <center>
                <div class="travel_mainDiv">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="Images/travel4.jpeg">

                    <h4 class="text-capitalize"><kbd>Yiga Choeling Monastery</kbd></h4>

                    <hr>

                    <h5 class="text-success text-left text-capitalize">I had visited in Oct 2019</h5>

                    <p class="text-muted text-left">One of the oldest Monastery in Darjeeling. It is situated in peaceful and beautiful landscape just 15 minutes walk from Ghoom Railway Station. We can see religious God and Goddess paintings believed by Buddhism inside which can give spiritual power to one who prays there with clean heart. From the compound of Monastery on a clear day one can have a scenery of hills all around which is great for nature lovers.</p>
                </div>
            </center>

            <!-- Movies -->
            <!-- Movies -->
            <!-- Movies -->
            <!-- Movies -->
            <div class="page-header" id="movies">
                <h2 class="text-capitalize">Movie Reviews</h2>
                <div class="bg-primary movie_head" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Avengers_Endgame">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></span> Avengers Endgame<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
                </div>
                <div id="Avengers_Endgame" class="collapse">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                        <img src="Images/movie1.jpeg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 movie_text">
                        <h5 class="text-success text-left text-capitalize"> Best Movie for MCU Fans
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                        </h5>
                        <p>You should have a minimal previous understanding of the movies or you’ll miss 40% of the fun.At minimum:Infinity WarCivil WarBlack PantherAge ofAnt Man and the WaspProblem is that the whole movie is homage to all movies. Yet you will enjoy it a lot.There is at the beginning of the movie a (spoiler alert) head dismemberment that is quite impressive. But most is comic book style figand battles.Must go to bathroom just before the movie because it does last 3 hours all worthwhile.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-primary movie_head" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#SpiderMan_farfromhome">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></span> Spider-Man: Far from Home <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
                </div>
                <div id="SpiderMan_farfromhome" class="collapse">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                        <img src="Images/movie3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 movie_text">
                        <h5 class="text-success text-left text-capitalize"> Nice Movie for Spider-Man Fans
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                        </h5>
                        <p>It might sound oxymoronic, but Avengers Endgame left us with a wholesome heartbreak. Our heroes brought back their fallen and saved the world from Thanos’s cosmic destruction plan. Yet, there was a price to pay, and our beloved Iron\Man AKA Tony Stark paid it. While it was undoubtedly painful to bid goodbye, the rest of our favourites seemed to have found peace. And so they should. In Spider-Man: Far From Home, the next step after the death and destruction of Avengers, our friendly neighbourhood Spider-Man AKA Peter Parker is off on a well-deserved break with his classmates. While the loss of Tony Stark looms over him at all times, he just wants to leave aside the superhero suit for a while and finally enjoy life like a 16-year-old should. And like every teenager, he wants to get that first kiss from the girl he likes.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-primary movie_head" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#the_lion_king">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></span> The Lion King<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
                </div>
                <div id="the_lion_king" class="collapse">

                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                        <img src="Images/movie2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 movie_text">
                        <h5 class="text-success text-left text-capitalize"> Nice for one time
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                        </h5>
                        <p>2019’s The Lion King is a ‘live action’ remake of the 1994 original animation flick which went on to become an iconic film for all ages. Those who have watched the original Lion King will vouch for its strong emotional connect, rousing, heartbreaking moments that left a lasting impression and of course the legendary soundtrack and background score. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-primary  movie_head" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Frozen_2">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></span> Frozen 2<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
                </div>

                <div id="Frozen_2" class="collapse">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                        <img src="Images/movie4.jpeg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 movie_text">
                        <h5 class="text-success text-left text-capitalize"> Beautiful, Enchanting and Layered
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                        </h5>
                        <p>Bottom Line: The film will bring back the magic for your t(w)een, who was a fan of the original. But, it could be too intense for preschoolers. There are some spoilers below in the full review. Full Review: While it had some great songs, and I thought better instrumental music, I still like the music from the original better. The reprise of "Into the Unknown" at the end of the movie is sung by Panic! At the Disco - clearly meant to appeal to the original Frozen fans, who are now tweens and teens.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-primary  movie_head" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Toy_story4">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></span> Toy Story 4<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
                </div>

                <div id="Toy_story4" class="collapse">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                        <img src="Images/movie5.jpeg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 movie_text">
                        <h5 class="text-success text-left text-capitalize"> Nice Movie for Toy Story fans
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                        </h5>
                        <p>Hollywood has a distinct ability to breathe life into objects and the Toy Story franchise is perhaps the best example. This time, writers Andrew Stanton and Stephany Folsom introduce some new characters in this emotional roller coaster. While we still have the good ol’ Woody holding the center stage, the focus is now on Forky. As the name suggests, it’s just a fork with strings for hands and broken wooden sticks for toes. But the fact that you feel instantly connected with him and root for him symbolises the brilliance of the film’s nuanced writing and near flawless execution. Tony Hale’s perfectly pitched voice and an endearing character arc gives him the edge. Director Josh Cooley promptly pulls Toy Story 4 into the action mode as the motley group of toys are taken on a road trip. The fun adventure begins right from the start, as we see Woody inadvertently getting in trouble for always doing the right thing.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Movies -->
            <!-- Movies -->
            <!-- Movies -->
            <!-- Movies -->

            <div class="page-header col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="environment">
                <h2 class="text-capitalize">News about environment</h2>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 environment_li">
                    <h4> LEGO plans to find a replacement material for bricks by 2030. </h4>
                    <img src="Images/e1.jpeg" class="img-responsive col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                    <p class="list-group-item-text col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
                        In an effort to be more environmentally responsible, LEGO have said they aim to stop manufacturing bricks made of plastic resin and are considering other options, which could include hemp. According to Telegraph World, the company makes 60 billion blocks a year. While LEGO want to replace the harmful plastic used in their products, they also require the new material to meet the high standards that allow the blocks to work as they always have, especially with the effective “clicking” together is a key aspect of the iconic coloured block.
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 environment_li">
                    <h4>Amazon deforestation and number of fires shows Summer of 2019 not a normal year.</h4>
                    <img src="Images/e3.jpeg" class="img-responsive col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                    <p class="list-group-item-text col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
                        The perceived scale of the Amazon blazes received global attention this summer. However, international concerns raised at the time were countered by the Brazilian Government, which claimed the fire situation in August was 'normal' and 'below the historical average'.An international team of scientists writing in the journal Global Change Biology say the number of active fires in August was actually three times higher than in 2018 and the highest number since 2010.
                    </p>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="page-header col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="books">
                <h2 class="text-capitalize">Books</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <h3>Bill Gates</h3>
                <h4>
                    <mark class="header_entreprenuer">
                        <i>
                            <sup><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i></sup>
                            Reading is still the main way that I both learn new things and test my understanding.
                            <sup><i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i></sup>
                        </i>
                    </mark>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal 1 -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 book" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#First_spc_encycloepadia">
                <img src="Images/s1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <hr>
                <p class="text-primary">First Space Encyclopaedia</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="First_spc_encycloepadia">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal Content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">First Space Encyclopaedia</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <img src="Images/s1.jpg" class="img-responsive image_modal">
                            <p class="p_modal">Zoom off into the galaxy and investigate all the planets, from Earth to Mars with First Space Encyclopaedia. Packed full of stunning photography, quizzes and amazing facts, children will become space experts in no time. Covering everything from observatories and rockets, to the solar system and the death of stars, children will discover all about space and space travel. <br>
                                <a href="https://www.amazon.in/First-Space-Encyclopedia-DK-Reference/dp/0756633664"><b>BEST BUY LINK</b></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal 2 -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 book" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Man_on_the_moon">
                <img src="Images/s2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <hr>
                <p class="text-primary">Man on the Moon</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="Man_on_the_moon">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal Content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Man on the Moon</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <img src="Images/s2.jpg" class="img-responsive image_modal">
                            <p class="p_modal">It was 1969 and no one had ever set foot on the moon. Some said it couldn't be done. But astronauts Mike Collins, Buzz Aldrin, and Neil Armstrong were going to try . . . Here in picture book format is the amazing true story of the first moon landing, when a man set foot on an unexplored world and showed us that the boundaries of our world were limitless."[A] perfect introduction to space, the space program, and exploration. Thrilling!" (Kirkus Reviews)"The milestone event [is] a great idea for a picture book!" <br>
                                <a href="https://www.amazon.in/Moon-Picture-Puffins-Anastasia-Suen/dp/0140565981"><b>BEST BUY LINK</b></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal 3 -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 book" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Space_encyclopaedia">
                <img src="Images/s3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <hr>
                <p class="text-primary">Space Encyclopaedia</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="Space_encyclopaedia">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal Content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Space Encyclopaedia</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <img src="Images/s3.jpg" class="img-responsive image_modal">
                            <p class="p_modal">The universe is bigger than you can ever imagine and it is full of fascinating facts that will astound you! This Space. Encyclopaedia is your guide to the infinite wonders of outer space. Browse through the pages and know more about galaxies, planets, stars and much, much more!. <br>
                                <a href="https://www.amazon.in/Space-Encyclopaedia-Books-Editorial-Team/dp/9384625957"><b>BEST BUY LINK</b></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal 4 -->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 book" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#th_no_plc_like_spc">
                <img src="Images/s4.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <hr>
                <p class="text-primary">There's No Place Like Space: All About Our Solar System</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="th_no_plc_like_spc">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal Content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">There's No Place Like Space: All About Our Solar System</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <img src="Images/s4.jpg" class="img-responsive image_modal">
                            <p class="p_modal">Au revoir, Pluto! In this beloved revised classic, beginning readers and budding astronomers are launched on a wild trip to visit the eight planets in our solar system (per the International Astronomical Union’s 2006 decision to downgrade Pluto from a planet to a dwarf planet), along with the Cat in the Hat, Thing One, Thing Two, Dick, and Sally. It’s a reading adventure that’s out of this world! <br>
                                <a href="https://www.amazon.in/Theres-No-Place-Like-Space/dp/0679891153"><b>BEST BUY LINK</b></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <section id="contact">
                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3593.5644421287925!2d84.13601581449583!3d25.751913615291706!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3992652401dd7bd3%3A0x386638c956771554!2sCHANDRASEKHAR%20NAGAR%20POLICE%20CHOWKI!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1619516946341!5m2!1sen!2sin" width="500" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                <hr style="width: 100%;">
                <img src="Images/Rishabh%20Yadav.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" height="125px" width="225px">
                <h3 style="font-size: 25px;">Rishabh Yadav</h3>
                <div class="contact_1">
                    <a href="mailto:yadvendra.chaudhari@gmail.com?subject=Hi">
                        <h5 style="font-size: 18px;"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;yadvendra.chaudhari@gmail.com</h5>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

CSS code:

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#contact iframe {
    width: 100%;
}

.contact_1 h3 {
    display: inline;
}

.contact_1 a {
    text-shadow: none;
}

input {
    background: grey
}

.travel_mainDiv {
    border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    float: none;
}

.travel_mainDiv img {
    width: 100%;
}

.travel_mainDiv h5 {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.travel_mainDiv hr {
    width: 230px;
}

.travel_mainDiv p {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.movie_head {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 6px 22px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.movie_head i {
    float: right;
}

.movie_text span {
    color: #ff7700;
}

.environment_li {
    margin-top: 13px;
}

.environment_li h4 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    padding: 8px;
}

.environment_li img {
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.environment_li p {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.header_entrepreneur {
    line-height: 2;
}

.book {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.book hr {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.modal-content {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.image_modal {
    display: inline-block;
}

.p_modal {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.modal-body {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Please answer this question, you will be thanked.

Comment: maybe it's just becoz the contact section height is too short and it is actually jumping there but still it is that height away from bottom of the window

Comment: Hi, before looking into this problem you may like to run your code through a validator as it has multiple errors, including repeated ids (an id must be unique). This will make it easier to find your problem. Also, is there a reason for making contact a section and everything else divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your `id="environment"` content is out of this div, This ID's `div` closed before content!

Comment: Hi Hossein, thanks for the answer, I did what you said but it didn't worked perfectly, so in the contacts section, I changed it from <section> to <div> and gave some bootstrap classes to the div and it worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: Please. A part of your tag was closed incorrectly and you should have checked the closing order of the codes by the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section id="contact">... </section>
```

=>

Its take height from body tag. So, need to clear content section. Here is two option. you can use ...

1. Need add blank div before content section

   Example:-

```
<div style="clear:both; display:block"></div>
```

```
<section id="contact"> Content Here.... </section>
```

2. Need to add class="col-xs-12" on

   ```
   <section id="contact">.....</section>
   ```

   Example:-

```
<section class="col-xs-12" id="contact">.... </section>
```